# Unbound breakpoint in vscode when importing from package.json

Tags: package.json, vscode-debugger

I have a nest js server and use vscodes javascript debug terminal. The breakpoints were working correctly until I added import from `package.json` like this:

```js
import { name } from '../../package.json';
```

All the breakpoints became unbounded after adding this import and restarting the server.
Fot the meantime I changed my code to use `process.env.npm_package_name` instead importing it from the `package.json`.

Is there a way to use import from `package.json` with working debugger?